# Hello World in angularJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've already spent more than 30 minutes to write this simply hello world but it still doesn't work.
here's my html:

```
<html lang="en-us" np-app="weatherApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJs weather forecast SPA</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        html, body, input, select, textarea{
            font-size:1.05em !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS Weather</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="LogController">
        {{ firstMessage }}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's my js file:

```
var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', []);
weatherApp.controller('LogController', function($scope){
    $scope.firstMessage = "Hello fucking world" ;
});
```

there's no error in console. What am I doing wrong?

[***JSFIDDLE HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/ek7u2465/)

Comment: While I agree with the close votes on "simple typo", the downvotes seem kind of unnecessary, it's easy enough to put a typo in and not see it, and to struggle with a brand new language and not understand what to look for.

Comment: Votes indicate perceived value to the community, not a personal judgement. Besides, if the question is closed, they're annulled.

Comment: More discussion on that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284566/downvote-vs-vote-to-close-question

Comment: One thing is for sure... votes intended to counter other votes are simply inappropriate. Also, downvotes encourage users to delete their own questions when they're of limited or no value. This is a good thing.

Comment: I agree on the countervotes, they weren't me :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `ng-app` not `np-app`

```
<div class="container" ng-app="weatherApp" ng-controller="LogController">
    {{ firstMessage }}
</div>
```

Then select `No wrap in head` option to `Frameworks & Extensions` second dropdown

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ek7u2465/4/)

Comment: @George you could accept this answer now.. :)